# How to check the progress of a process in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to make some operations that could take a few hours in pandas, I;m using a for loop, each iterations take a little more than a second and I have to make about 10k, so I want to know how much of the work have been already done.

I can print 'i' every 10 iterations or so, but I wonder if there is already some tool to implemented in python to know this sort of things.

```
for i range(10000):
    do something
    print i
```

Also I'm not sure if printing i could affect the performance in a significant way

Comment: Try defining the fuinction and then applying it using [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) or [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) from pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) from pandas.

Let's suppose you have a pandas Data Frame with three columns and you want the logarithmic of the column '1' and rewrite it as a new column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# set seed
np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(12).reshape(-1,3))
print('Original')
print(df)

df['log'] = df[1].apply(np.log)
print('Modified')
print df
```